# appixia's cartapi for Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, appixia

appixia's cartAPI is best solution I have found on web for webservice.
[Git Source](https://github.com/appixia/cartapi-plugin-prestashop/)

I am Using same API's for Prestashop from last 1 year for 1.5 version. 
Now I have upgraded my prestahop version from 1.5 to 1.6 with latest one. After upgrade I have installed same cartAPI module from Git source but it's not working as they mentioned in it's supported version document,

```
Prestashop 1.5.x - Tested on 1.5.0.17 through 1.5.3.1
```

- Can anybody help me why this is not working?
- Is there anyone who can upgrade this API to work with 1.6 version?
  [Requested to GIT](https://github.com/appixia/cartapi-plugin-prestashop/issues/3)
- Now if I have to try for upgrade what type of changes have to make, please
  give suggestions.